# Element multiplication - every three elements

Tags: c++, arrays, complex-numbers

I have an array of hundreds of (complex number) elements. I need a way to multiply every three elements together and add to the next batch of multiples. What's the most efficient way to do this?

For example;

```
(myArr[0]*myArr[1]*myArr[2])+(myArr[3]*myArr[4]*myArr[5]*)+(myArr[6]*...myArr[n])
```

Maybe this can be done quite easily but I'm missing something. Thanks in advance

Comment: May I suggest using a so-called loop?

Comment: Efficient in what sense?

Comment: In terms of speed (but I'll parallelise the code in CUDA later - so not that important atm). The size of the array can change as the array comes from another part of the code, and its not necessarily a multiple of three which is why I can't get my head around a loop. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the size of the array is a multiple of 3...
This code works...

```
long long int Ans=0;
for(int i=0;i<size; i+=3)
{
     Ans += (arr[i]*arr[i+1]*arr[i+2]);
}
```

If you are very serious about number of multiplications...
this may be helpful..

```
long long int Ans=0;
for(int i=0;i<size; i+=3)
{
     if(arr[i] && arr[i+1] && arr[i+2])//check if anyone of them is zero..
     Ans += (arr[i]*arr[i+1]*arr[i+2]);
}
```

If the size is not a multiple of `3`, then append few elements  at the end so as to make it a multiple of 3, and initialize them with `1` (or `0` depending on your specifications..) and use the same above method.

EDIT:

You need to add this snippet above the `for` loop.

```
while(size%3!=0)
{
     arr[size++] = 0; //or 1 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quite response. However, it isn't a multiple of three, which is why I'm struggling to think of a way to loop it.

Comment: The test `i<size-3` is not correct: consider the simple case `size==3`. The usual `i<size` will do.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that. I forgot the assumption that its a multiple of 3..while writing that line.. updated it.